# Is it possible to print mysql load_file data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I`m trying to use MySQL load_file to print local file text in php, but my code doesn't work. Is there any clear example of doing this?

This is my code :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db=mysql_select_db('test', $link) or die(mysql_error());
$src=mysql_query("SELECT LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\lab\source.txt')", $link) or die(mysql_error());
$data=mysql_result($src,0);
echo "Source is : ".$data[0];
```

Comment: escape your backslashes properly first and try again.

Comment: @Ghost You mean this? LOAD_FILE('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\lab\\source.txt')

Comment: yes try to use that to escape the slashes properly and check the results

Comment: Maybe the real problem is that `$data[0]` will only print the first character of the file? What if you do try 

    `echo "Source is : ".$data;` instead?

Comment: You right but that was not the only one